# What is Inlet-valve Mach index?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, engines, car

What is the meaning of this statement "In a reciprocating engine the flow of intake charge takes place through the intake valve opening which is varying during the induction operation. **Also**, **the** **maximum** **gas** **velocity** **through** **this** **area** **is**  **limited** **by** **the** **local** **Sonic** **velocity**"

Comment: Please give more details.

Comment: Could u explain the underlined statement?

Comment: Has to be below mach 1...?

Comment: Read the section on **Choked Flow** for the [Venturi Effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Venturi_effect) & remember that the speed of sound is dependent density & temperature of the medium it is travelling through - *hence local sonic velocity*.

Comment: Hi @Naveen_official could you add an illustration or sketch to your question in order to help other to answer it

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If the local velocity of the inlet charge through that area hits mach 1, the flow is "choked" by the presence of a normal shock wave. I have never heard of flow rates high enough to induce choked flow in an intake runner tube, however; this seems unlikely.